# 'as much as' or 'as many as'

Tags: grammar

having next sentence

> The amount of people who are concerned about reforestation is nearly as twice as much (many?) as those who don't care.

I've got next question:
How is more correct to say - `much` or `many`? On one hand, we have `amount` - so it looks like we should use `much`, on other hand `people` - and `many`. Or we have no difference in this case and can choose any?

Comment: Don't use _amount_ with _people_; use _number_ instead. People are count, not mass. And then you can just say _as large as_ without having to worry about _much_ or _many_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To know when to use *much* or *many* depends on if it refers something countable or uncountable.

In this specific example *people* is countable, so it's correct to use *many*.

Also, using "The amount of people" might be correct grammar but it does sound slightly strange or awkward.

According to [Dictionary.com Unabridged
Based on the Random House Dictionary, © Random House, Inc. 2017.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/amount)

> Usage note:
>    The traditional distinction between amount and number is that amount is used with mass or uncountable nouns ( the amount of paperwork; the amount of energy) and number with countable nouns ( a number of songs; a number of days).
>       Although objected to, the use of amount instead of number with countable nouns occurs in both speech and writing, especially when the noun can be considered as a unit or group ( the amount of people present; the amount of weapons) or when it refers to money ( the amount of dollars paid; the amount of pennies in the till).

Comment: I reformatted your quote using block quote, which is selectable from the top of the format menu marked with ["] quote marks. In the future, please use this, or mark with a wedgie [>] to set off quotes.